# Firefox does not update itself via the help menu

Tags: windows-7, firefox

When I click the 'Check for updates' button in the 'About Firefox' window, it simply gives me the 'Updates available at https://www.mozilla.org/firefox/' message below.

[image: Image of the "About Firefox" window]

I don't recall fiddling with `about:config` recently so I have no idea what might have caused such behaviour. I run Firefox 45.0.2 x86_64 under Windows 7 Enterprise x86_64. I have automatic updates turned off.

Comment: Where is the "Check for updates" button that you're clicking? If I go to `Help` -> `Firefox Help` it brings up the online documentation, but if I go to `Help` -> `About Firefox` it checks for updates automatically, with no button.

Comment: Main menu (the hamburger button) -> open help menu (the question mark button) -> about firefox. I have automatic updates turned off.

Comment: I've got a spare computer with an old version of Firefox (35.0.1) that I just tested this with. I turned off the automatic updates (set to `Never check for updates`) and then opened the `About Firefox` menu using the steps you listed, but as soon as I do it checks for an update and downloads it (the only button available for me is `Restart Firefox to Update` after it has already pulled them down). It might be worth adding a screenshot of the screen you are seeing as well as the message and add it to the question.

Comment: You got it: [link](http://i.imgur.com/dnEIwCd.png). This is what it gives me after I click `Check for updates`.

Comment: Is this PC on a domain? If so it could be that your IT department manages FF updates to ensure compatibility.

Comment: Another possibility is that your operating system does not support GTK3. Mine doesn't. So no more Firefox upgrades possible for me. FF-46 on Linux switched from GTK2 to GTK3.

Comment: Burgi, nope, the PC isn't on any domain.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be an issue with your ability to store the update on your machine. Ensure that you have full permissions (especially `Write`) for the `%LocalAppData%\Mozilla\updates` folder (which should translate to something similar to `C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Mozilla\updates`).

This might also be an issue to do with the fact that you have automatic updates turned off. During my testing, I was unable to reproduce the message when the settings `app.update.auto`, `app.update.enabled` and `app.update.service.enabled` were all set to `true`. Try modifying all three of these (available through `about:config`) to `true` and seeing if your issue persists.

## Explanation

After looking through the Firefox source code, it seems that the `Updates available at https://www.mozilla.org/firefox/` text is displayed in `aboutDialog-appUpdater.js` when `gAppUpdater.aus.canApplyUpdates` is false. The following text in the [documentation of `nsIApplicationUpdateService`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIApplicationUpdateService#Attributes) describes the value of `canApplyUpdates`:

> `true` if the Update Service can download and install updates. Indicates if the current user has access privileges to the install directory. **Read only.**

This would imply that you don't have the correct access to the Firefox install directory (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox` on my machine), but after some testing it appears that removing write access to `%LocalAppData%\Mozilla\updates\` (along with changing the above `app.update` settings to `false`) will cause the message to appear. Not having access to the installation directory may also pose a problem, but since it isn't getting to the point of applying the update (and therefore modifying installation files), it appears that this isn't the issue you're currently facing.

Comment: I have tried that and it didn't work. I have also checked the permissions on the `%LocalAppData%\Mozilla\updates\` directory. I have read and write permissions there; what I don't have is something named 'special permissions'. I'm not near that machine at this moment so I can't check if enabling those special permissions would help.

Comment: Granting the user the write and modify permissions on FF's default installation directory (in `%programfiles%`) set the update process in motion. Strange; I think I had updated FF under default permissions at least once before.